# Bash: escaped quotes in subshell

Tags: bash, quoting, escape-characters, subshell

When I execute the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    files+=$file
done < <(find -type f -name '*.c' -print0)
echo "${files[@]}"
```

I do not get the same result as this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
find_args="-type f '*.c' -print0"
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    files+=$file
done < <(find $find_args)
echo "${files[@]}"
```

How can I fix the second scenario to be equivalent to the first one?

My understanding is that, because there are single quotes in the double quotes, the single quotes get escaped, which produces a bad expansion that looks something like that:

```
find -type f -name ''\''*.c'\'' -print0
```

Comment: FYI, in bash 4+, try `readarray -d '' files < <(find . -type f -name '*.c' -print0)`.  For details on this, you could run `help readarray` but that will just tell you that readarray is a synonym for mapfile, so `help mapfile` instead :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with subshells. See [How do I store a command in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note, you have a typo. You left off the `-name` flag in the second example.)

One approach is to put the args in an array and pass the array appropriately to `find`...

```
#!/bin/bash
find_args=(-type f -name '*.c' -print0)
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    files+=$file
done < <(find "${find_args[@]}")
echo "${files[@]}"
```

The format `${foo[@]}` expands to all of the elements of the array, each an individual word (rather than expanding to a single string). This is closer in intent to the original script.

Answer (score 4):

[BLayer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382288/135943) is correct, but to deconstruct what's really happening here (ignoring the typo of the missing `-name` primary):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    files+=$file
done < <(find -type f -name '*.c' -print0)
echo "${files[@]}"
```

In the shell started by process substitution (`<(...)`), the following command is parsed by bash:

```
find -type f -name '*.c' -print0
```

Because the glob `*.c` is quoted, bash does *not* expand it.  However, the single quotes are stripped off.  So when the `find` process starts, what it sees as its argument list is:

```
-type
f
-name
*.c
-print0
```

Note that these arguments are separated with *null bytes*, not with spaces or newlines.  This is at the C level, not at the shell level.  This has to do with how programs are executed using `execve()` in C.

Now to contrast, in the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
find_args="-type f -name '*.c' -print0"
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    files+=$file
done < <(find $find_args)
echo "${files[@]}"
```

The value of the variable `find_args` is set to:

```
-type f -name '*.c' -print0
```

(The double quote marks are not part of the value, but the single quote characters *are.*)

When the command `find $find_args` is run, as per `man bash`, the token `$find_args` is subject to parameter expansion *followed by* word splitting *followed by* pathname expansion (a.k.a. glob expansion).

After parameter expansion, you have `-type f -name '*.c' -print0`.  Note that this is *after* quote removal.  So the single quotes will not be removed.

After word splitting, you have the following as separate words:

```
-type
f
-name
'*.c'
-print0
```

*Then* comes pathname expansion.  Of course `'*.c'` isn't likely to match anything as you don't usually put single quotes in your filenames, so the result would *likely* be that `'*.c'` will be passed as a literal pattern to `find`, and thus the `-name` primary will fail on all files.  (It would succeed only if there is a file whose name starts with a single quote and ends with the three characters `.c'`)

---

Edit: Actually, if there is such a file, the glob `'*.c'` will expand to match that file and any other such files and then the *expansion* [the actual file name] will be passed to `find` as a *pattern.*  So whether the `-print0` primary will ever be reached or not depends on (a) whether there is only *one* such filename, and (b) whether that filename, interpreted as a glob, matches itself.

Examples:

If you run `touch "'something.c'"`, then the *glob* `'*.c'` will expand to `'something.c'`, and then the `find` primary `-name 'something.c'` will match that file as well and it will be printed.

If you run `touch "'namewithcharset[a].c'"`, the glob `'*.c'` will be expanded to that by the shell, but the `find` primary `-name 'namewithcharset[a].c'` will *not* match itself—it would only match `'namewithcharseta.c'`, which doesn't exist—so `-print0` would not be reached.

If you run `touch "'x.c'" "'y.c'"`, the glob `'*.c'` will expand to *both* filenames, which will cause an error to be output from `find` because `'y.c'` isn't a valid primary (and it can't be as it doesn't start with a hyphen).

---

If the `nullglob` option is set, you'll get different behavior.

See also:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, you need to:

- declare the `$files` variable as an array as by default it will be scalar and `var+=something` on a scalar does string concatenation (or arithmetic addition if the scalar has been given the *integer* attribute). Or use the `var+=(something)` syntax (which would automatically convert the variable to an array).
- initialise the variable (as unset or to an empty list), as otherwise you may inherit an initial value from the environment.

Doing:

```
files=()
while ...
  files+=$file # or files+=("$file")
done
```

Would be enough unless the `files` variable has previously been declared as an associative array earlier in the script (in which case `files+=something` would be like `files["0"]+=something` and `files+=("$files")` would be an error).

If you can't guarantee `files` haven't been defined as an associative array earlier in the script, you may need:

```
typeset -a files=()
```

instead, though that would have the side effect of limiting the scope of the variable to the enclosing function. `typeset -ga files=()` doesn't work properly as a work around for that in `bash` as it would declare the variable in the global scope. `unset files; files=()` might not work either as `unset files` in some cases may reveal the `files` variable from an outer scope (which may be an associative array) instead of unsetting it.